# How to push new project code to specific branch in existing github repository?

Tags: git, github, command, git-branch

I added the origin of remote repository in my code.
My existing repository have three branches: `master`, `test`, `user`.

But after adding and confirming the remote `origin` by command '`git remote -v`', the '`git branch --list`' command is displaying only one branch that is `master`.

I don't know if it is exactly pointing to that origin where I want to push the code.
I want to push the new code to `test` branch.

git branch -avv

```
 master                     first commit
 origin                     first commit
* test                       first commit
 remotes/origin/master      Update register.tsx
 remotes/origin/test        Update next.config.js
 remotes/origin/aman        june 25
```

I want to push it to remote test branch and delete local branches origin, test and master.

```
 git switch -c test
 fatal: only one reference expected
```

And when I tried to switch to `remote/origin/test` branch from vscode it says branch 'test' already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need:

```
git fetch
```

Then a `git branch -avv` will show you all branches and their SHA1.

Note: only [`git branch --all/-a`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--a) would list local  *as well as* remote branches.

You can then compare `master` and `origin/master` commits.

Explanation: see "[Git Internals - The Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)"

> ```
> $ git remote add origin https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit
> ```
>
> Running the command above adds a section to your repository’s `.git/config` file, specifying the name of the remote (`origin`), the URL of the remote repository, and the refspec to be used for fetching:
>
> ```yaml
> [remote "origin"]
>   url = https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit
>   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

The fetch refspec is the reason why a git fetch would populate the `origin` namespace with all the remote branches Git can find from the remote repository.

---

> I want to push the new code to test branch.

If you have:

- code currently being modified, but not yet added/committed
- only one local branch (`master`)

You can do:

```sh
git fetch
git switch -c test
git add .
git commit -m "Code for test"
git rebase origin/test
git push
```

Since you do a `git fetch` first, the local branch test will follow automatically `origin/test`.
See [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess):

> If `<branch>` is not found, but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a *matching* name, treat as equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

The `rebase` step ensures your local commit is done/reploayed on top `origin/test`.

---

> I have one local commit but that was not intentional.
> I want to push the code to `remote/test` branch and rest local branches like `master`, `origin` and `test` I want delete them all

Then I would, to make sure I don't loose anything:

- clone your remote repository elsewhere, directly on the `test` branch (using [`git clone --branch/-b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--bltnamegt))
- import your current code
- make a new commit in the test branch
- push test

That is:

```sh
cd /path/to/existing/local/repo
cd ..
git clone -b test https://github.com/<me>/<myRemoteRepo> repo2
cd repo2
git --work-tree=../repo add .
git commit -m "Import from original local repo"
git push
```

Comment: I have two test branches how to delete current test branche                                                      
  master                  
  origin                  
* test                 
  remotes/origin/master    Update register.tsx
  remotes/origin/test          Update next.config.js
  remotes/origin/aman      june 25

Comment: @aman Do you mean one local, one remote? Don't hesitate to edit your question: you can format your edits there, while there is no formatting in comments.

Comment: yes, i want delete all local branches and out of them two have same names as remote branches test and master.

Comment: @aman You see to have only one local branch though. My answer would apply.

Comment: when I tried to switch to test branch it says branch already exists

Comment: @aman I did not see your edit. Do you want to replace all local test branch by the remote test history? Do you have local commits on test branch you want to keep?

Comment: no i have one local commit but that was not intentional.....I want to push the code to remote/test branch and rest local branches like master, origin and test I want delete them all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234498/discussion-between-vonc-and-aman).